# VBA if combobox exists then

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

I modified a Word document, adding 4 ComboBoxes, each with some dropdown choices.  It works fine, except when a user deletes a section of the document that contains one of the ComboBoxes.  If they do that, when they re-open the doc, they get "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

Is there a way I can add code that will check to see if the ComboBox exists on opening the document and either perform the code or ignore it?  I've tried using "On Error Resume Next" to no avail.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
On Error Resume Next

    ComboBox2.List = Array("Choose One", "SSN", "Employee ID")
        If Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "SSN" And Me.ComboBox2.Value <> "Employee ID" Then
            Me.ComboBox2.Text = Me.ComboBox2.List(0)
        End If
        If ComboBox2.Value = "Choose One" Then
            TextBox3.Value = ""
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Value = "SSN" Then
            TextBox3.Value = ""
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Value = "Employee ID" Then
            TextBox3.Value = "Employee ID must be unique by employee and " & _
                             "all numeric with a max of 9 digits."
        End If
Error = 0

End Sub
```

If the user removes ComboBox2, then re-opens the doc - it bombs out and gets that error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below was written in Word 2010. I believe, however, that it will run smoothly on Word 365 as well. It should be pasted into the `ThisDocument` module of your VBA project.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_Open()
    ' 10 Nov 2017

    Dim Cn As String                            ' control name
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim MissingControl As Boolean
    Dim Msg As String

    For i = 1 To 2
        Cn = "ComboBox" & i
        If Not ShapeExists(Cn) Then
            MissingControl = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If MissingControl Then
        MsgBox Cn & " doesn't exist", _
               vbInformation, "Corrupted document"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With ActiveDocument
            With .ComboBox2
                .List = Array("Choose One", "SSN", "Employee ID")
                If .ListIndex < 0 Then .ListIndex = 0
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    ' 10 Nov 2017

    Dim Msg As String

    Msg = IIf(ComboBox2.ListIndex = 2, _
              "Employee ID must be unique by employee and " & _
              "all numeric with a max of 9 digits.", "")
    TextBox3.Value = Msg
End Sub

Private Function ShapeExists(Cn As String) As Boolean
    ' 10 Nov 2017

    Dim Shp As InlineShape
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If StrComp(Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name, Cn, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ShapeExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Shp
End Function
```

Observe that the `ComboBox2_Change` event will occur when the list for ComboBox2 is set. However, the ListIndex will be 0, and this will cause TextBox3 to be cleaned. The message text will appear when you change the value of ComboBox2.

Comment: Hi Variatus!  Thank you very much for this.  I'm a newbie at best with VBA, so please forgive any weird coding and dumb questions.  These are actually in a Word document rather than a userform.  What would need to be changed to make this work in a Word doc?

Comment: What happens when you try to run my code? Please quote error message and the line of code which gets highlighted when you press Debug on the error message dialog box?

Comment: When I try to step through that code, I get:  "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined."  The line of code highlighted is:  " Set Ctl = Controls(Cn)"

Comment: Try `Dim Ctl As Shape` and `Set Ctl = ActiveDocument.Shapes(Cn)`. Can you tell me how you create the ComboBoxes. I'm groping in the dark because I can't reconstruct your ComboBoxes in a document I create here.

Comment: OK - those new lines of code seem to help a little.  When i step through, it is identifying "Cn" as "ComboBox1" - but when i get to the "Set Ctl" piece, it's saying that "Ctl = Nothing", so doesn't "see" that ComboBox1 is really there.  If it helps, I'm using the Office 365 version of Word.  To create the ComboBoxes, i just used the Developer tab in Design mode and inserted ActiveX Combo Boxes.

Comment: I was able to recreate your environment and replaced the code in my answer with a version that should work for you without much modification.

Comment: Hi Variatus - ok, using the new code, here's what happens when I step through it:  When I get to the "If Not ShapeExists(Cn) Then" line, it goes straight to the Private Function section.  When it gets to the "If StrComp(Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name, CN, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then" line, I get an error (Run-time error '01': Object variable or With block variable not set).